# How can you search for files that don't contain a certain string

Tags: regex, notepad++, bulk

How can you search with **NotePad++** using **Find in Files** with **Regex** for files that don't contain MYSTRING, but contain some markers, see example:

File1

```
<xxxx>...
  <YY>...
    "MYSTRING"
  </YY>...
</xxxx>...
```

File2

```
<xxxx>...
  <YY>...
    ....
  </YY>...
</xxxx>...
```

I want only File2 to match.

**...** means random chars that I don't care about (including new line)

I tried lots of things, including all sorts of lookarounds, but no luck.

Something like this:

```
MODIFICATION_TIME.*MYSTRING.*</Entity
```

but the opposite, MODIFICATION_TIME that is missing MYSTRING after it.

**.** needs to match newlines also

Comment: can you please show some real examples? the regex will depend on what those dots can include, and on what "MYSTRING" is. also please show what you tried.

Comment: What if there is `"MYSTRING"` outside the markers ?

Comment: Try `<marker>(?:(?!MYSTRING).)*?</marker>`

Comment: "MYSTRING" can't be outside the markers. I need to be able to search across multiple lines.

Comment: I rephrased it, I hope is more clear now what I tried and what I want

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it:

```
MARKER(?!.*MYSTRING)
```